# Porting Ubuntu Touch to Galaxy S4 International LTE, where to create the UCM directory and how to call it?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm currently trying to port Ubuntu Touch to the Galaxy s4 International LTE (GI9505/ jfltexx).

I've come to the point where I need to create a UCM directory but I don't know where and how I should call it. By "looking at `/usr/share/alsa/ucm/apq8064-tabla-snd-card/`" is the local Ubuntu PC directory or a directory on the downloaded CM meant? Same thing for `/proc/asound/cards` which should give a hint about what the directory should be called.

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xfb200000 irq 51
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0xfb080000 irq 17
```

I dont think the directory should be called anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late but you can find the /usr/share/alsa/ucm/apq8064-tabla-snd-card/ in the downloadable preinstalled image :)